# query based on contents of a cell

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do an importrange query based on the contents of a particular cell. I want it to find all the rows that where Col1 = the contents of cell A1

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Cost Per SKU!a1:q1000"),"select * where Col1 = "&A1&"").
```

The query doesn't find any rows even though there are rows in the URL with the value in A1.

Thanks

Comment: if answers helped you or solved your issues pls accept them by marking the given answer

Answer (score 1):

if A1 is numeric number:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Cost Per SKU!A1:Q1000"), "where Col1 = "&A1, )
```

if A1 is text string:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Cost Per SKU!A1:Q1000"), "where Col1 = '"&A1&"'", )
```